# golang losing precision while converting float32 to float64?

Tags: go, floating-point, double

In Golang, it seems that when a float64 var first convert to float32 then convert float64, it's value will change.

```
a := -8888.95
fmt.Println(a)                    // -8888.95
fmt.Println(float32(a))           // -8888.95
fmt.Println(float64(float32(a)))  // -8888.9501953125
```

How can I make it unchanging

Comment: *"How can I make it unchanging"* -- by not doing the conversion. When you do conversion the [*"result value is rounded to the precision specified by the destination type."*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions). Because the original `a` contains the result of plain assignment, there was no rounding, but when you convert, then there's rounding. Either don't convert, or live with the change.

Answer (score 13):

`float64` unequivocally has **more** precision than `float32` in its binary representation. Your example shows how Go mirrors this idea in formatting: printing a float64 by default will show more decimal digits (i.e., more precision) than a printed float32.

If you force the program to format all values to high precision, you'll see what's really going on:

```golang
a := -8888.95
fmt.Printf("%.20f\n", a)
fmt.Printf("%.20f\n", float32(a))
fmt.Printf("%.20f\n", float64(float32(a)))
```

Outputs:

```
-8888.95000000000072759576 // original 64-bit value
-8888.95019531250000000000 // converted to 32-bit
-8888.95019531250000000000 // re-converted to 64-bit
```

Here you can see the original value is extremely close (yet not equal) to the literal value of `a`. Converting to 32-bit increases the inaccuracy by 8 to 9 orders of magnitude. Re-converting to 64-bit has no added change.

In summary: you're getting a loss of **accuracy** of the **binary value** when converting to float32. Then, you're experiencing a loss of **accuracy** in the **printed value** when converting to float64 because Go prefers to format float64 values with higher **precision**. Note the differentiation of [accuracy and precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision) here.

It's not possible in general to convert from float64 to float32 without losing accuracy. Here's a simple argument for why that is:

- There are more possible float64 numbers (~2^64) than float32 numbers (~2^32)
- Therefore multiple distinct float64 numbers must map to the same float32 number during conversion due to the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).
- Therefore the conversion is not reversible due to the loss of information.

Due to the underlying similarity of the float64 and float32 formats, numbers that can be exactly represented by a float32 can be also be exactly represented by a float64, and they can be converted in either direction without loss of accuracy. The issue is that numbers can only be exactly represented by these binary floating point formats when they meet certain conditions:

- The number must be rational (can be expressed as a fraction of integers)
- The denominator of such fraction must be a power of two (1, 2, 4, 8, etc.)
- The numerator and denominator must not exceed certain size limits, which depend on what floating point standard you are using.

You may find that the probability that any random number you are dealing with will meet these conditions is quite low. For example, if you express `-8888.95` as a fraction of integers, you will get `-177779/20`. Since 20 is not a power of two, this number cannot be exactly represented by either float format and so accuracy issues ensue.